# How to specify SSL certificate for WSO2 Identity Server in Docker?

Tags: docker, wso2

I'm using the [WSO2 Identity Server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2is) and want to specify my own SSL certificate. The [documentation I have found so far](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Creating+New+Keystores) revolve around Identity Server being installed directly on the target machine rather than in a container.

Comment: i think you need just mount volume for `wso2is-5.7.0/repository/resources/security` and put there `*.jks` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to set up a proxy in front of wso2. I did this using NginX:

https://medium.com/@oliver.zampieri/self-signed-ssl-reverse-proxy-with-docker-dbfc78c05b41